# How do I highlight cells based on the day of the week in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight the cells in Google Sheets that are days of the week (text only) based on today's date.

Basically, I have a column that has M-T-W-TH-F-S-SU in it (undated, just text) and I want it to highlight the day of the week it currently is with conditional formatting or whatever. So if it's Tuesday today, Tuesday will be highlighted. Keep in mind the cell doesn't have a date in it currently, I need it to show as text. How can I do this with a simple formula or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd")=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,
 {{"M","Mon"};{"T","Tue"};{"W","Wed"};{"TH","Thu"};{"F","Fri"};{"S","Sat"};{"SU","Sun"}},
 2,0)),1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: You're a beast! Wow tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Please select the relevant column (A assumed) and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
=weekday(today())=switch(A1,"M",2,"T",3,"W",4,"TH",5,"F",6,"S",7,"SU",1,"")
```

with highlighting of your choice. It is little more than half the characters of the other answer.