# How to highlight a cell containing the name of a weekday in a row based on =Today() in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, weekday

I have a sheet with the names of the weekdays in row 1. I want to highlight the cell containing the value "Fri" on a Friday. I used the example from this answer: [How do I highlight cells based on the day of the week in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628427/how-do-i-highlight-cells-based-on-the-day-of-the-week-in-google-sheets)

However, I need a row highlighted, and the example given is a column. I managed to make a semi-working example by switching the VLOOKUP to HLOOKUP and adjusting the parameters.

```
=IF(TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd")=IFERROR(HLOOKUP({{"M","Mon"};{"T","Tue"};{"W","Wed"};{"TH","Thu"};{"F","Fri"};{"S","Sat"};{"SU","Sun"}},  B1:H1, 1)),1)
```

However, it highlights Tue through Fri on a Friday!

Any chance someone could help me out? Here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nhyc9r-A3IFaxfBz-HsvOeVTUFSDD3auHJb33ckg_5o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd")=B1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Sheets formula already provided is to make use of Apps Script:

```
function colorDayOfTheWeek() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let date = new Date();
  let today = date.getDay();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, 8).setBackground("white");
  ss.getRange(1, today+1).setBackground("yellow");
}
```

Using a script can be easier to manage and it is more versatile when it comes to the tasks you have to achieve. The above one makes use of the `getDay` method which returns the day of the week and based on the returned value, it colors the cell accordingly.

#### Before

[image: before the script]

#### After

[image: after the script]

#### Reference

- [JavaScript Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay);
- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).